# MySql faster to use separate query or subquery?

Tags: mysql, sql

The following query took **0.2630 sec** to select 2477 rows from the total of 85862 rows in the table

```
(SELECT 1, `name` FROM `tab1` WHERE `reg` = 5 and `lang` = 9 and `queue` = 
   (select min(`queue`) from tab1 where `reg` = 5 and `lang` = 9)
limit 5)
UNION ALL
(SELECT 2, `name` FROM `tab1` WHERE `reg` = 1 and `lang` = 3 and `queue` =
   (select min(`queue`) from tab1 where `reg` = 1 and `lang` = 3)
limit 5)
UNION ALL
(SELECT 3, `name` FROM `tab1` WHERE `reg` = 3 and `lang` = 11 and `queue` =
   (select min(`queue`) from tab1 where `reg` = 3 and `lang` = 11)
limit 5)
```

Will there be, theoretically, any benefit to performance if, in order to detect `MIN(value)` of a column, I will run a separate query instead of sub-query?

columns `reg` and `lang` are indexed, `queue` is not

EXPLAIN:

```
| id | select_type | table       | type        | possible_keys | key      | key_len | ref  | rows| Extra
-----+-------------+-------------+-------------+---------------+----------+---------+------+-----+---------------------------------------
| 1  | PRIMARY     | tab1        | index_merge | reg,lang      | lang,reg | 1,1     | NULL | 813 | Using intersect(lang,reg); Using where
| 2  | SUBQUERY    | tab1        | index_merge | reg,lang      | lang,reg | 1,1     | NULL | 813 | Using intersect(lang,reg); Using where
| 3  | UNION       | tab1        | index_merge | reg,lang      | lang,reg | 1,1     | NULL | 830 | Using intersect(lang,reg); Using where
| 4  | SUBQUERY    | tab1        | index_merge | reg,lang      | lang,reg | 1,1     | NULL | 830 | Using intersect(lang,reg); Using where
| 5  | UNION       | tab1        | index_merge | reg,lang      | lang,reg | 1,1     | NULL | 834 | Using intersect(lang,reg); Using where
| 6  | SUBQUERY    | tab1        | index_merge | reg,lang      | lang,reg | 1,1     | NULL | 834 | Using intersect(lang,reg); Using where
|NULL| UNION RESULT| <union1,3,5>|  ALL        | NULL          | NULL     | NULL    | NULL | NULL| Using temporary
```

Comment: Run `show indexes from tab1` and then run `explain {your query}` and post the result in the question.

Comment: Consider providing proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET.

Comment: *...to select 2477 rows from...* How did you get more than 15 given the `limit 5` on your queries?

Comment: it returned 15 rows, but I guess it scanned 2477 that met WHERE condition as per `explain`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL should be running the "min" subquery only once for each group.  Putting the value in a separate variable shouldn't really affect performance.

If you want to optimize the performance of this query, then create an index on `tab1(reg, lang, queue)`.  This index will allow direct lookups for values without going through the "index merge" step.

Comment: Gordon, this is the second time when you clarify things for me. Thanks.

Comment: Wow! I've added the composite index on those columns as you suggested and outright it's reduced the time of the same query to **0.0080 sec**. What an improvement! I was not aware of such feature as composite keys before. Thanks again.